# Get function parameter with url JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Well, i got a page that load 3 galleries, and each gallery have the "view gallery" button. Everytime this button is clicked it should load the whole gallery in another page. It should call a function that loads the whole gallery and redirect to the page with all the images. But i can't make it work. The parameter of the function is passed through the value of variable "x", but i don't know how to put this value in the function, so the redirection work perfectly. Like this:

```
while(x <= 3){

    imgs.innerHTML += "<div id='gal"+x+"' class='row'>";
    imgs.innerHTML += "<div class='eight columns'>";
    imgs.innerHTML += "<h4>Galeria "+x+"</h4>"

for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
    galeria[i] = "foto"+x+"_"+(i+1)+".jpg";
}
for(var i = 0; i < galeria.length; i++){
    imgs.innerHTML += "<img src='img/"+galeria[i]+"' class='imgs-galeria'>";
}

imgs.innerHTML += "</div>";
imgs.innerHTML += "</div>";
imgs.innerHTML += "<a id='veja' href='pics.html' onclick='maisGaleria("+x+");'><div id='link'><p>Veja mais</p></div>"

//it loads the page pics.html and send the x value to the function. I need to start the function with this value in pics.html, but instead, it just load pics.html with no images.
x++;
```

}

The function:

```
function maisGaleria(n){

    var galeria = new Array();
    var img = $("#gallery");

        img.innerHTML = "<div class='row'>";
        img.innerHTML = "<div class='six columns'>";
        //imgs.innerHTML += "<h4>Galeria"+n+"</h4>";

        for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
            galeria[i] = "foto"+n+"_"+(i+1)+".jpg";
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < galeria.length; i++){
            img.innerHTML += "<img src='img/"+galeria[i]+"' class='imgs-galeria'>";
        }

        img.innerHTML += "</div>";
        img.innerHTML += "</div>";
}
```

the page pics.html

```
<body onload="maisGaleria();">
<div class="center">
<div class="row">
<div class="four columns top">
    <h5></h5>
</div>
<div class="eight columns menu">
    <ul>
        <a href="index.html"><li><h4 class="menu-list">Home</h4></li></a>
        <a href="galeria.html"><li><h4 class="menu-list">Galeria</h4></li></a>
        <a href="sobre.html"><li><h4 class="menu-list">Sobre</h4></li></a>
        <a href="contato.html"><li><h4 class="menu-list">Contato</h4></li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row galeria">
<div id="gallery" class="container">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div id="footer">
<div class="four columns">
    <h4></h4>
</div>
<div class="eight columns img-footer" id="social">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what does the javascript console tells u ? `var img = $("#gallery"); ... img.innerHTML` i doubt it work, `img[0].innerHTML` or `img.html('content here')` are the correct ways.

Comment: it just don't return any errors... it was working, but i though it was ugly too, thanks for the tip ! About the question, i just don't get nothing in the console, i think i should get the parameter using the url but i actully have no idea how to do this...

Comment: With img[0].innerHTML it just return:img[0] is undefined

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant using img[0] will return undefined because the jQuery is getting the element by ID, just like `document.getElementById()`. If the OP used a class name, then `[0]` would be of some use as getting by class name will list an array of elements like `getElementsByClassName()`. To fetch the first element of that class you would have `getElementsByClassName()[0]`.

Comment: Thanks @NewToJS for the explanation ! Any tips for my problem ? Thank you!

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle please and put a comment in your source code where you want the redirection to take place? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sorry, i'm new into this... i never did one, this is my first one, is it good enough ? https://jsfiddle.net/grkj16aq/2/

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the structure of your gallery. the variable x is undefined because it isn't being declared, some of your `innerHTML` is overwriting the previous `innerHTML`. I can't really be of much help unless you can explain step by step of how you expect your gallery to function and the image directory setup by adding comments in your source code. Also the reason for the variable `x`. **Edit:** Could you also explain what is and isn't working.

Comment: @NewToJS https://jsfiddle.net/grkj16aq/3/ here, it is all complete now, i explained it all in the end of the javascript section between /**/, and put the link to the website i'm talking about so it could be easier to understand !